# Would Bessel beam laser propulsion create true constant acceleration?

Tags: rocket-science

I've heard that Bessel beams don't diffract. If Bessel beams continuously bombarded a laser sail, would it keep the ship constantly accelerating from our frame of reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the apparent acceleration would continually diminish as the object being propelled approached the speed of light.

Comment: You can only have a non-difracting Bessel beam for a distance equal to the radius of the emmiting source. After that point the beam begins to spread.